# Is it possible to install php8.1 whithout installing ondrej/php PPA?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-20.04, php-8, php-8.1

The thing is that I have to run php7.4 and php8.1 in the same apache server (running in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS focal).
I achieve this in a VirtualBox machine with the same specifications following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04)

When I tried the same thing in the production server `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` throws (`ERROR: '~ondrej' user or team does not exist.`). Also if I enter the link in the sources.list and then try to install the key shows `connection timeout`.

Server is delicate there are other apps being used in production. I cant install archives with security risk.

After some research I conclude that the firewall of that server is not letting me install this key and I dont have access to change configuration files of the firewall (Im not sure about this but none of the answers worked).

There are no proxys, I have tryed installing the key from a different port, installing software-properties-common, reinstalling ca-certificates, modifying resolv.conf.

My question after all this is: Is there a way to install php8.1 and make it run simultaneously with php7.4 in an apache server without installing `ppa:ondrej/php`?

Any advice is usefull I dont know what more to try. (sorry my bad english)

Comment: If the production server is not under your control, find out who is reponsible for that machine, contact that person and clarify your requirements with her/him. In the end you have a change request for that systems configuration. From your question it appears to me, the installation procedure is blocked for a reason, so while learning for yourself how offline installation works on a Debian based system like Ubuntu for packages (the systems administration handbook of the OS should cover it IIRC) you may technically solve it, but you should not override the policy improvidently.

Comment: Running two or more apps on a "kitchen sink" server is virtually guaranteed to lead to a situation like this where you cannot make necessary changes to the server for one app without affecting unrelated apps. You should leverage containers or VMs to isolate the applications from each other and ease the long-term administrative burden.